# Magento 2 Add existing simple product to configurable product greyed out

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm trying to add an existing simple product to a configurable product.

I clicked on **Add products Manually** in the configurable product.
[image]

But the the simple product I'm trying to add to this configurable product is greyed out. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I just figured it out. it was because I already have another simple product that has the same attribute as the one I was trying to add to configurable product. A configurable product can not have more than one simple product that have the same attribute added.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue but when I looked into it and found that I already have another simple product that has the same attribute as the one I was trying to add to the configurable product. A configurable product can not have more than one simple product that has the same attribute added.